# ¿Cómo convertir una string en int, incluyendo chars?

Tags: c, string

Estoy buscando una función que convierta todos los caracteres de un `string` en `int`, incluyendo los que son `char`. Los que son `char` se convertirian a su equivalente en `int`.

Por ejemplo:

```
char var[] = "1ab2";
int num = funciónMágica(var);
printf("%d",num);
```

Salida:

```
197982
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacer esto?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: Si sabes como hacerlo manualmente, ¿qué te impide escribirlo como programa?

Comment: Creo que estás confundido: '1' es tan "char" como 'z'. Igual lo que quieres es que en el caso de los enteros no usar el valor ASCII sino el valor representado, pero eso es tan sencillo como un `if`. En todo caso, ¿puedes indicarnos qué has probado y decirnos qué problema te has encontrado?

Comment: De momento he probado pasarlos todos a `char`, pero se pasaban todos

Comment: Voy a probar lo de `if`

Answer (score 2):

> Estoy buscando una función que convierta todos los caracteres de un `string` en `int`

No necesitas ninguna función, puedes hacer la conversión directamente:

```
char letra_a = 'a';
int numero_a = letra_a;

printf("numero a: %d", numero_a); // imprime 97.
```

Dado que tu función "*mágica*" convierte las letras a su valor decimal y no reinterpreta los números, seguramente  necesites usar `isdigit`:

```
void magia(char *caracteres)
{
    for (char *c = caracteres; *c; ++c)
    {
        printf((isdigit(*c) ? "%c" : "%d"), *c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como podria implementar eso sin usar punteros ni operaciones ternarias?

Comment: @ByRussX no puedes hacer "*eso*" sin usar punteros. El operador ternario lo puedes cambiar por un `if`.

Comment: Bueno, se podría usar un índice ... :)

Comment: @eferion un índice es aritmética de punteros azucarada :P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya, pero no usas punteros directamente... es lo mismo pero dicho de otra forma